# Will an exception thrown from a noexcept function parameter's constructor immediately result in a call to std::terminate()?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, noexcept

Given the following class declaration:

```
class phone_number
{
public:
    explicit phone_number( std::string number ) noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible< std::string >::value );
}

phone_number::phone_number( std::string number ) noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible< std::string >::value )
    : m_originalNumber{ std::move( number ) }
{

}
```

Will the following line of code end up calling `std::terminate()` immediately due to the noexcept specification if an exception is thrown from the string constructor?

```
const phone_number phone("(123) 456-7890");
```

Comment: The string constructor from `const char *` is called by *you*, not by the `phone_number` constructor. The move constructor doesn't throw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since all the parameters are evaluated *before* the function is invoked, an exception, emitted by a parameter's constructor, would not violate `noexcept` contract of the function itself.

To confirm this, here's what I've tried, approximating your example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const char *)
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
};

void f(A a) noexcept
{

}

int main()
{   
    try
    {
        f("hello");
    }
    catch(std::exception&)
    {
        cerr<< "Fizz..." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output, unsurprisingly, was `Fizz...` and the program exited normally.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has two kinds of exception specifications:

#### *dynamic-exception-specification* (deprecated)

which looks like this:

```
void foo() throw(x, y, z)
```

In this case, if an exception is thrown within `foo` that is not in the set x, y or z, then `std::unexpected()` is called. By default, this will call `std::terminate()` but you can interpose yourself by setting your own unexpected handler, which may even throw an x, y or z in order to allow the program to continue. Of course, no-one ever does this.

#### *noexcept-specification* (since c++11)

which looks like this:

```
void foo() noexcept; // same as noexcept(true)
void foo() noexcept(true); // not allowed to throw exceptions
void foo() noexcept(false); // allowed to throw exceptions
```

This is where it gets interesting because the behaviour is *different* if `foo() noexcept(true)` does actually throw an exception. The standard mandates that `std::terminate()` shall be called.

You have no opportunity to catch the exception or otherwise correct the situation. A solemn promise was made and broken - end of program.

#### From §15.4  [except.spec]

> 10 Whenever an exception of type E is thrown and the search for a handler (15.3) encounters the outermost
>   block of a function with an exception specification that does not allow E, then,
>
> (10.1) — if the function definition has a dynamic-exception-specification, the function std::unexpected() is
>   called (15.5.2),
>
> (10.2) — otherwise, the function std::terminate() is called (15.5.1)